# All my if statements are evaluating to true when they shouldn't be

Tags: java

Me very new programmer, I'm making a simple vending machine program, and so far I have two items. I setup a scanner that takes user input and if statements that evaluate to true if a user enters a specific input. When I enter "A" for example it prints both if statements when it should only print one.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    double milkPrice = 2.00;
    double sodaPrice = 2.25;

    System.out.println("Please make a selection:");
    String userResponse = scnr.next();

    //If user input is A or a
    if (userResponse.equals("A") ||
            userResponse.equals("a"))
            {
        System.out.printf("%s", "You have bought Milk for  "); System.out.printf("%1.2f %n", milkPrice);
            }

    System.out.println("Please make a selection:");
    //If user input is B or b
    if  (userResponse.equals("B") ||
            userResponse.equals("b"));
    {
        System.out.printf("%s", "You have bought Soda for "); System.out.printf("%1.2f %n", sodaPrice);
    }
        scnr.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement has a semicolon where there should not be one:

```
if  (userResponse.equals("B") ||
    userResponse.equals("b"));
```

A typical if-statement, without brackets, will execute just the single next line if the condition evaluates to `true`. However, your single next line is an empty line denoted by `;`. Then, the next block of text in brackets is executed no matter what.

Comment: In other words: **delete the semicolon after the *if***

Answer (score 0):

You have an erroneous semicolon at the end of your second if statement.

Take out the semicolon and let the if statement condition flow into the response.